# Using sed to remove LF but keep CRLF in file

Tags: sed, csv

I have unquoted newline LF in CSV file that I want to load to database, causing error. Can I use sed or other tools readily available in Linux to remove this newline?

Actual line ending for the CSV file is CRLF, as observed using Notepad++ pilcrow.

Comment: replace LF with what?

Comment: edited the title

Comment: Do you have an example of a few lines of data with this feature? If the data is properly quoted, a CSV parser would be able to read it, and it would be _easy_ to transform or delete embedded newlines.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` implementations that support `RS` values other than single-character ones, such as GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS = ORS = "\r\n"}
     {gsub("\n", ""); print}' < in.csv > out.csv
```

With `sed`:

```
CR=$(printf '\r')
sed -e :1 -e '$q' -e "/$CR\$/b" -e 'N;s/\n//;b1' < in.csv > out.csv
```